# Detecting global touch on screen

Tags: c#, touch, hook

I want that after a touch is detected in windows, my app will start doing some things.
I failed catching global touch, I tried to use this event: Touch.FrameReported, but it does not work, can I do it with hooking?

Now I am trying to use WM_TOUCH to hook touch, but I can't find how to do it globally with c#.

Comment: *but it does not work* - in what way it doesn't work?

Comment: Nothing happened, the event is not triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use globalmousekeyhook, in that MouseMove event fires the TouchDown event.

Comment: I already looked about globalmousekeyhook, I couldn't find the Touch event.

Comment: I know it not have the TouchEvents, I also faced the same problem, but when I tried it with the MouseMove and MouseDown event it worked for me for Touch environment.

Comment: Now I am trying to use WM_TOUCH to hook touch, but I can't find how to do it globally with c#.